# getting error Extract pdf to text in python

Tags: python

Here is my code there is an occured in this code:

Error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pytopdf.py", line 23, in 
    text = str(pytesseract.image_to_string(im, lang = 'eng'))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\ufb01' in position 424: ordinal not in range(128)

```
import io
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
from wand.image import Image as wi
pdf = wi(filename = "sample2.pdf", resolution = 300)
pdfImage = pdf.convert('jpeg')
imageBlobs = []
for img in pdfImage.sequence:
    imgPage = wi(image = img)
    imageBlobs.append(imgPage.make_blob('jpeg'))
recognized_text = []
outfile = "out_text.txt"
f = open(outfile,"a")
for imgBlob in imageBlobs:
    im = Image.open(io.BytesIO(imgBlob))
    text = str(pytesseract.image_to_string(im, lang = 'eng'))
    recognized_text.append(text)
    f.write(recognized_text)
f.close()
```

Comment: Try encoding im to utf-8 before passing it to pytesseract.image_to_string.

Comment: How to encode?, can you explain me please?

Comment: i added this encode but its not working                                                             text = str(pytesseract.image_to_string(im.encode('utf-8', errors='ignore'), lang = 'eng'))